# .desktop files not executing via double click, only from terminal

Tags: gnome, icons, shortcuts, .desktop

When I try to **doubleclick-execute** a **.desktop** file it opens up the **GNOME Games launcher** and does nothing else. Even if i try to reset the opening application by right clicking and editing the properties, the default application still remains the games one (Icons don't work too).
**Executing** the file **via terminal**, using `gtk-launch filename.desktop`, **works fine**.
Is there a configuration file that I should edit or something more to reset?

I'm working on Ubuntu 19.04 with GNOME 3.32.1

Comment: What is the location of the .desktop file?

Comment: ~/.local/share/applications
and
/usr/share/applications

Comment: Let me get it right, you open on the locations in your Files application and then double-click a  .desktop file. Then instead of launching the associated application, it does nothing, right?

Comment: Exactly, even if they are the preinstalled applications in /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nautilus no longer allows the launching of .desktop files thru it. (nautilus)

The only way to double click > launch is to have the .desktop file on your Desktop.
Even then you'll need to set it to allow launching, likely thru the right click context menu.

Other file managers such as nemo aren't encumbered in this regard.

Comment: For those interested a CLI way of solving it has been found:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314919/creating-a-program-shortcut-on-the-desktop-entirely-from-the-terminal-in-ubuntu
...hope it helps you like it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could be permissions, directory permissions, `mount` options.

Use my `pathlld` script https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld to explore your access.